# Redirecting to custom 404 page in home directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble redirecting the 404 (incorrect url requests) to a 404 page (404.php) I developed and uploaded to the server.

The server has a Wordpress installation in the sub-folder /blog and all the 404 are getting redirected to wordpress blog's 404 page. I have set the redirection in .htaccess but is not working.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This is what I added in .htaccess, but it still redirects to the blog's 404 instead of the 404 page in root.

How can I override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all make sure that the 404.php is present in the proper location and http://www.example.com/404.php is working properly.

if both 404.php and .htaccess are present in the same root folder, then try changing following line in .htaccess file

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

to

ErrorDocument 404 /root/404.php

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` will only work if you have not specified rewrite rule in `.htaccess` eg:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Because wordpress has it's own [life cycle](https://wordimpress.com/the-wordpress-page-lifecycle-visual-graphic/) which uses URL rewrite in `.htaccess` to determine which page request are coming. WordPress has it's core mechanism to understand the current request. For example you have created a page name `hello-word`, when you go to `http://your_wordpress.com/hello-word` wordpress determines `hello-world` from URL and find in it's database whether it has `hello-word` page or not. If current page does not exist in database then it's mechanism automatically call theme 404 template which is located in currently active theme.

> Solution

Create a file in `wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/404.php` and change it's content. You don't need to specify `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in `.htaccess`. Read more how to create `404` template [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Comment: Ok. But I am having a different template and a different site in root. And I dont want it to redirect to the wordpress 404. Is there any way to override the wordpress redirection in .htaccess??

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by pasting this code on top of my wordpress theme's header.php file

```
 if ( is_404() ) {
      wp_redirect( '../404.php' );
      exit;
   }
```

And now the root/main site 404 page is getting loaded instead of wordpress blog's 404 page as intended. :)